# using default poster image with video and audio tags

Tags: javascript, php, html, ffmpeg

I have a web-application where users can share music and videos ( will be saved on sme-server utilized by Web-Application ) and as we know some audio /video files have posters/thumbnails included/attached with them.
NOW, I want to show those posters with audio or video in HTML5.
I know about poster tag, but it needs a separate image file to show. However, I want to show image file attached with song (audio / video).
Any suggestion related any `java-script` or HTML api will be appreciated.
I know about obtaining poster images with `ff-mpeg`(or similar libraries), but that will add an extra work load on my server. Thanks.

Note:-I may consider any server side efficient solution alo.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you would only need to run ffmpg once when uploading the video, very low usage. HTML5 `<video>` tag needs the poster as a separate image, and the `<audio>` tag has no poster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Video's, you can try generating video thumbnail on the fly as per [this ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22607886/377342). Check working example below (*Code is taken from [this link](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/01/04/capturing-html-5-video-to-an-image.aspx)*):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video width="470" height="255" id="video" poster="default-video-thumbnail.png" controls>
      <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
        "use strict";

        var video;
        var scale = 0.25;

        var initialize = function() {
          video = $("#video").get(0);
          // Calls click event after a certain time
          setTimeout(function() {
            $(captureImage);
          }, 1000);
        };

        var captureImage = function() {
          var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
          canvas.width = video.videoWidth * scale;
          canvas.height = video.videoHeight * scale;
          canvas.getContext('2d')
            .drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

          var img = document.createElement("img");
          img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
          $("#video").attr('poster', img.src);
        };

        $(initialize);

      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What above script does, on Page load there will be a default video thumbnail shown with Play icon, on page load the script will be called (after 1 sec) which will generate a thumbnail from video and replace the default thumbnail. These thumbnails won't be saved on server.

For Audio, you can try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22606452/377342), the answer also has [JSFiddle demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/s9eqL/2/):

Comment: It's good, but very first scene in video is not always a thumbnail.  However, it's a good work-around than nothing :)