# How to add audio to a HTML image?

Tags: html, audio, onclick, dreamweaver, playback

I'm still new to all this, but I'm trying to add audio mp3 sound to an HTML image, which is played when clicked on. How can I do this right?

I've already tries a few things, like the '' tag, or installing java-based stuff, like soundmanager2, however none of them seems to work.
The problem is, that I don't know how to use them properly.

I'm using dreamweaver CS6, in which there should be an option "behaviour"--> play sound, but it's not there, so I'm lost with all this.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve that using [Audio and Video DOM methods](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) `play()` and `pause()` onclick of image [working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/s9eqL/2/)

```
<audio id="audio_play">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>

<img src="http://bit.ly/1kX7D49" onClick="document.getElementById('audio_play').play(); return false;" />

<img src="http://bit.ly/1mq0tIt" onClick="document.getElementById('audio_play').pause(); return false;" />
```

Comment: Thanks this does indeed work. One more thing, how is this with links? I've tried to add your solution to the image inside of the link, but then the link doesn't work, or if I add it directly into the link, it still does not work.

Comment: I've found a workaround, when I change onmouseclick to onmouseover, then the problem goes away.

Comment: Can you post your problem in fiddle or else though we could trace the issue with click?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 Audio Tag:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

More Information:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Answer (score 0):

You won't need any player because html5 is able to play sound files. Check out this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

You can use jQuery to load the sound file.

```
$('#my_image').click(function(){
   //some code to load the audio file here
})
```

Maybe you'll need some further code or css to hide controls and stop audio from playing etc.