# How do I Add sound when I reach a particular section of the HTML page

Tags: html, audio

So I am an absolute beginner to this and was wondering on how can I add sound (in this case Bell Sound) to an HTML page. The sound needs to play when I scroll down to the section of the page and reach the bell image.

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<img style="max-width: 100%" alt="" src="<?= 
enter code herebase_url('assets/bootstrap/')? 
>image/ringabox.png">
<audio autoplay="true" >
<source src="<?= base_url('assets/bootstrap/')?>image/ht1.wav" type="wav">
</audio>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
audio.play();

// or with an ID

var audio = document.getElementById("mySoundClip");
audio.play();
```

Any Help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: after a quick search I found this [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604532/how-to-add-audio-to-a-html-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Javascript you can do it like this :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var hT = $('#scroll-to').offset().top,
       hH = $('#scroll-to').outerHeight(),
       wH = $(window).height(),
       wS = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (wS > (hT+hH-wH) && (hT > wS) && (wS+wH > hT+hH)){
       console.log('H1 on the view!');
   }
});
```

See source on this thread : [Trigger event when user scroll to specific element - with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561480/trigger-event-when-user-scroll-to-specific-element-with-jquery)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

```
var audio = $("#mySoundClip");
var bellTop = $('#bell').offset().top;
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop >= bellTop){
        audio.play();
    }
});
```

The variable scrollTop has the amount of pixels scrolled.
You can also calculate the percentage scrolled by calculating document and window height. eg.

```
var wHeight = $(window).height();  // window Height
var dHeight = $(document).height();  // document Height
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  // pixels scrolled
var scrollable_area = dHeight - wHeight  // scrollable area
var pScrolled = Math.floor(scrollTop/trackLength * 100);  // percent scrolled
```