# How to get HTML5 video thumbnail without using poster on safari or iOS?

Tags: ios, html, video, safari, mp4

I have embedded HTML5 video with mp4 format. How to get thumbnail image like poster without using "poster" attribute. This problem coming on Safari and iOS. I have added video like below mentioned code.

```
<video height=350 id='TestVideo' webkit-playsinline><source src='test.mp4' type=video/mp4></video>
```

On Chrome, IE, Firefox first frame of video coming as thumbnail image, but not coming on Safari and iOS.

Comment: can you add your code?

Comment: There are a solution with autoplay but it will work only in IOS 10+

Answer (score 34):

simply add `preload="metadata"` in `video` tag and set `#t=0.1` at url src, it will get the frame of 0.1s of your video as thumbnail

however, the disadvantage of this solution is when you click to play the video, it always start at 0.1s

```
<video preload="metadata" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4#t=0.1" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: This methods works perfectly fine. I have no issue using it on iOS. Tested on Chrome Androïd and desktop and no issue so far. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: This method does not work if you are using blob.url as video src

Comment: This clever method worked flawlessly, and solved my longstanding problem of getting the native thumbnail to show once the clip finished loading! Thank you so much!
It also replaces the poster attribute as desired, and the 0.1s offset doesn't matter in my use case, so this is a perfect solution for my use case.

Comment: Great recommendation!

Comment: Note that you can also use a smaller offset, e.g. `0.001` (1ms), it'll still display the thumbnail.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do this without storing server side images it is possible, though a bit clunky... uses a canvas to record the first frame of the video and then overlay that over the video element. It may be possible to use the URL for the Canvas as a source for the Poster (eg `video.poster = c.toDataURL();`) but that requires correct CORS setup (not sure if the video was on your own server, and if you have control over that, so took the safest option). This will work best if video is correctly encoded for streaming (so MOOV atom is at the front of the video, otherwise it will be slow to draw the overlay - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836206/html5-video-not-streaming-and-taking-90-seconds-to-load/40943383#40943383) for more detail)

The `HEAD` contains styling for the video and the overlay (you will need to adjust sizing and position to suit your application)

```
<head>
  <style>
    video_box{
      float:left;
    }
    #video_overlays {
      position:absolute;
      float:left;
      width:640px;
      min-height:264px;
      background-color: #000000;
      z-index:300000;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

In the `BODY` you will need the `div` for the overlay and the video. The overlay div has an `onclick` handler to hide the overlay and start the video playing

```
<div id="video_box">
  <div id="video_overlays" onclick="this.style.display='none';document.getElementById('video').play()"></div>

    <video id="video" controls width="640" height="264">
      <source src="BigBuck.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>

  </div>
</div>
```

Finally you will need code that will load the video, seek to the first frame and load the visual into a canvas that you then insert into the overlay

```
<script>

function generateOverlay() {
    video.removeEventListener('seeked',generateOverlay);  / tidy up the event handler so it doesn't redraw the overlay every time the user manually seeks the video
    var c = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    c.width = 640;
    c.height = 264;
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 264); // take the content of the video frame and place in canvas
    overlay.appendChild(c); // insert canvas into the overlay div
}

    // identify the video and the overlay
    var video = document.getElementById("video");
    var overlay = document.getElementById("video_overlays");

    // add a handler that when the metadata for the video is loaded it then seeks to the first frame
    video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
    }, false);

    // add a handler that when correctly seeked, it generated the overlay
    video.addEventListener('seeked', function() {
    // now video has seeked and current frames will show
    // at the time as we expect
        generateOverlay();
    }, false);

    // load the video, which will trigger the event handlers in turn
    video.load();

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on iOS.

Thumbnails can be displayed without the poster attribute by the following method. It also supports blob urls.

```js
// videoE: HTMLVideoElement
videoE.src = "...";
videoE.load();　// please load()
```

demo
https://codepen.io/arayutw/pen/NWLVpXK

Comment: Thank you! Calling `video.load()` worked for me. In my case I had a data URL and the `#t=0.1` approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

this is a bit late but we had the same scenario. I can't use the attribute 'muted' because my videos are podcasts. This is what I came up with and I hope to share it with future visitors. What I did is load the video in the body tag, drew a canvas, retrieved as base64 and applied to the video as the background image.

Since my video should be fixed 150px in height, I computed the aspect ratio so that whatever height and width of the actual video, it will be resized into 150px height and dynamic width.

```
$('body').append('<video class="checkmeload" style="position:absolute;top:-10000px" controls preload="auto" playsinline src="//src-here"><source src="//src-here" type="//videotype-here"></video>');

$('body').find('.checkmeload').on('loadeddata', function(){
    var video = $('.checkmeload');

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    aspectratio = (video[0].videoWidth / video[0].videoHeight);
    newwidth = (150 * aspectratio);
    canvas.width = newwidth;
    canvas.height = 150;

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(video[0], 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

    $('body').find('.checkmeload').remove(); 

    $('#myvideo').css('background-image','url("'+dataURI +'")');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Source: [How to set the thumbnail image on HTML5 video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075875/how-to-set-the-thumbnail-image-on-html5-video)

This worked for me:

```
<img src="thumbnail.png" alt="thumbnail" />
/* code for the video goes here */
```

Now using jQuery play the video and hide the image as

```
$("img").on("click", function() {
  $(this).hide();
  // play the video now..
})
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use separate image or poster for video because video coming dynamically and I don't want to rework by adding separate image. You have any idea to first frame of video set as a poster.

Comment: No which plugin can I use?

Comment: It's called popcorn.js

Check these 2 links:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323053/dynamically-using-the-first-frame-as-poster-in-html5-video

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607572/video-html5-is-it-possible-to-display-thumbnail-from-video-on-a-specific-time

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution?

Comment: Thank u I will try popcorn.js.

Comment: I upvoted because as long as you can trigger a video play via jquery on all platforms then its very neat! Havent tested it however...have you?

Answer (score 0):

Add `#t=0.001` at the end of the video URL.

https://muffinman.io/blog/hack-for-ios-safari-to-display-html-video-thumbnail/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30519222)