# How to get video thumbnail from url in React Native

Tags: react-native, video, video-thumbnails

I have videos that I'd like to present as thumbnails before a user clicks on them for the full video. They are not local, I only have the url, like this: https://filev4.subiz.com/fiqbjssxydufxauruqxi-video_test.mp4 . Is there a RN component or library to do this? Because I see this is cod to get video thumbnail for ios: [Getting a thumbnail from a video url or data in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347562/getting-a-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-or-data-in-iphone-sdk#4330647).

and here is code to get thumbnail for android: https://medium.com/@mujtahidah/get-thumbnail-video-from-url-android-f71533168228.

and library: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video for react native can get thumbnail of video for both of android and ios but it's make app frezee and crash if you load a lot of video, so i just want to get only thubnail of video from url, not load all video, I find some day,
I try with this: https://github.com/chadsmith/react-native-video-preview but nothing work.

This https://github.com/lucasbento/react-native-thumbnail-video get only thumbnail from youtube.

This: https://github.com/phuochau/react-native-thumbnail get only thumbnail from local, not from url.

I try many way but still... Someone can help?

Comment: it's not React specific, but fairly generic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255841/how-to-get-html5-video-thumbnail-without-using-poster-on-safari-or-ios/43242180#43242180

Comment: Thank, but i think it's not solution

Comment: What solution did you find for this? Thanks

Comment: @NicoaraTalpes Not yet :D

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh Can you take a look at github.com/phuochau/react-native-thumbnail/issues/35 for me? I am trying to solve the same overall problem as you. Thank you

Comment: Hey everyone. Has anyone solved this issue?

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh have you been able to find any workaround for this?

Comment: @WasifJameel I quit React Native a long time ago, it's terrible. I never come back again.