# How to put a poster of a captured image of the video using preload = "none"?

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm doing a system and in search has many videos as a result, leaving the loading slow, so I put the tag preload = "none", but the poster of the video turns black because nothing was uploaded yet, I wanted a way to get some image of the own video and put it as a poster of it, being something more dynamic.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: you will need to either process the video server side (use ffmpeg to extract the first frame as a poster) or use a script like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255841/how-to-get-html5-video-thumbnail-without-using-poster-on-safari-or-ios/43242180#43242180 ... I would also make sure you optimize video so MOOV atom is at the start (see link in answer) to make that happen much faster

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the `<video>` tag, you can make a screenshot from the video and put this in the video tag:

```
poster="url/to/image.jpeg"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem is that several random videos are sent to the system through an external camera. It's impractical to have to print out each video and put in the tag.
I would like to use something like: `poster: "url/to/video.mp4#t=1" `
but this does not work