# No way to preload first video frame on iOS Safari?

Tags: html, ios, video, safari, mobile-safari

I have a simple HTML5 video embed that displays a blank (white) frame when loaded on iOS. On desktop browsers (including Safari) and Android the first frame of the video is displayed.

I understand that you can avoid this by setting an explicit poster image, but I'm hoping I can avoid having to set up a transcoding service to extract the first frame of the videos. I understand that Apple has probably chosen this route to limit the bandwidth use for mobile users, but in this instance it's just overkill to set up a transcoding service.

I've played around with the preload attribute, but neither setting it to 
`auto` or `metadata` works. Is there any other way to display the first frame of the video without interaction from the user?

Here is a link to a pen where I am illustrating the problem.

https://s.codepen.io/webconsult/debug/oRmQva/vWMRwadNoNvr

And here is a screenshot of how the code is rendered on iOS simulator (same on real hardware) and in Chrome respectively.

[image]

Comment: does this do what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255841/how-to-get-html5-video-thumbnail-without-using-poster-on-safari-or-ios/43242180#43242180

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to work. It downloads the entire video, though, so not really feasible to use in practice.

Comment: if the video is encoded with the MOOV atom at the start (eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351136/preparing-mp4-file-for-html-5/27362604#27362604), and the server supports byte-range requests that will usually only require a small amount of the video to be downloaded before it can obtain the image

Answer (score 23):

You can use [Media Fragments URI](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/)

Just Append `#t=0.1` to the end of the video URL

Comment: This works! You're a life savor.  Can you help me understand WHY it works please?

Answer (score 5):

Try following code. This is work for me

```
<video src="video/video.mp4#t=0.5" playsinline controls preload="metadata">
      <source src="video/video.mp4#t=0.5" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: This one worked flawlessly for me, even without adding the source tag inside