# How to get HTML5 video player to display a preview on safari or iOS?

Tags: html, css, safari

If I embed an HTML5 video player on my site, it does not show any preview in Safari.

On other browsers I see a preview. 
I tried the top solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255841/how-to-get-html5-video-thumbnail-without-using-poster-on-safari-or-ios), but it didn't work for me, instead showing a black player with no play button.

This is roughly the code I'm using to render the player.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="some.url">
</video>
```

I expected to see a video player with a play icon and a preview image from the video in the background.

Instead I see a blank white background with just a play button.

Edit: 
Ideally I would be able to do this without the poster attribute, since I want to avoid doing additional processing on the video to extract an image + having to store and pipe through the image.

Answer (score 0):

You need put some additional attribute on your `video` tag.

```
<video controls poster="Here is the poster image what you want">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Ideally I would be able to do this without the poster attribute, since I want to avoid doing additional processing on the video to extract an image + having to store and pipe through the image.