# HTML5 video tag not showing thumbnail on mobile Safari without using poster

Tags: html, ios, video, safari, thumbnails

I used html video tag to display videos, I gave a set of videos from backend for user watching purpose, they are properly working & loading thumbnails on web, mpbile , android app too but not loading thumbnails on ios app & on safari browser. Since those videos are not auto played, I need thumbnails but without using poster. Please help me

Comment: there could be a number of reasons (mostly to do with saving data on mobile). Are the MP4 files encoded with MOOV atom at the front? If you don't want to generate the thumbnails yourself for posters then have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255841/how-to-get-html5-video-thumbnail-without-using-poster-on-safari-or-ios/43242180#43242180

Answer (score 0):

You say, "Since those videos are not auto played, I need thumbnails but without using poster." Why is it that you can't use `poster`? This attribute exists for exactly the use case you've described.  Sure, you can rely on the browser to make the "poster" for you, but a) that make take longer than you like, and b) not all browsers do it, or do it for all formats; c) making your own poster images (thumbnails) gives you complete control of what that image is.  Why is this solution, provided by the HTML5 spec, not meeting your needs?

Comment: becuase you don't have to do the expensive video processing of the video in order to get a thumbnail? not every website is just a portfolio where you have control over content, sometimes users can upload video themselves