# How to Create Thumbnail From Video In Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, html5-canvas

Im trying to create a thumbnail from a video file in typescript. This is my code below:

```
createThumbnail(video_url: string) {
   let canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
   let video: HTMLVideoElement = document.createElement('video');
   video.src = video_url;
   video.currentTime = 8;
   canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, 200, 200);

   canvas.toBlob(b => { resolve(b) }, 'image/png');
}
```

It creates the image alright but blank. It just creates a blank image. What i'm i doing wrong in my code ?

Comment: Posible duplicate of [video html5: Is it possible to display thumbnail from video on a specific time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607572/video-html5-is-it-possible-to-display-thumbnail-from-video-on-a-specific-time)

Comment: You should wait until the video elements emits the "loadeddata" or "canplay" event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

Comment: I added a canplay and loadeddata event and they dont run. Below is my code:

Comment: let canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
      let video: HTMLVideoElement = document.createElement('video');
      video.currentTime = 8;

      video.onloadeddata = () => {
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, 200, 200);
        canvas.toBlob(b => { resolve(b) }, 'image/png');
      }